# Castle Windsor: Can I get all instances of a type?

Tags: castle-windsor

I am registering a bunch of ITask implementations with Windsor using Named to separate them.  Is there a way a class can request all instances of ITask?

Comment: I'm writing my app container ignorant so I'm looking for a way that will work through the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windsor can do what you request via the `CollectionResolver` subdependency resolver:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
var kernel = container.Kernel;
kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(kernel));
```

Now, if you register multiple implementations of `ITask`, your task runner can have a ctor like this:

```
public TaskRunner(IEnumerable<ITask> tasks)
{
    // ...
}
```

which is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
container.ResolveAll<ITask>()
```

This blog post explains in detail how to do it in a container ignorant way:

[10 Advanced Windsor Tricks – 3. How to resolve arrays](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-3-how-to.html)

Similar to the other answer given.

Comment: Sorry I missed out a point which is my app is container ignorant so a container call would kind of suck...  that said if this is the only way I can hide it away in a TaskResolver which my main guy can ask for via it's constructor.